# Android Studio is not launching after installation

Tags: java, android-studio, android-ide, java-19

I had android studio arctic fox installed earlier but suddenly one day it did stopped launching. It is visible in task manager but the ide is not starting. I did explore all the questions related to it and tried all these methods:

1. Installed latest version of JDK (jdk-19)
2. Installed latest version of JRE (jre1.8.0_361)
3. Added JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME in system path variables.
4. Re-installed the latest version of Android studio (Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1)

None of the above solutions are working for me. I even tried to run *studio.bat* from *C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin* but I am getting the below error in the console:

```
2023-03-13 18:48:43,291 [  11466]   WARN - #c.i.d.PerformanceWatcherImpl - UI was frozen for 8276ms, details saved to C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.1\log\threadDumps-freeze-20230313-184839-AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390-8sec
2023-03-13 18:48:43,838 [  12013]   WARN - #c.i.u.j.JBCefApp - JCEF runtime library is not a JBR module (Use JBR bundled with the IDE)
2023-03-13 18:48:46,715 [  14890]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.d.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker - Error retrieving list of excluded patterns
java.io.IOException: Error code 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
        at com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.windows.WindowsDefenderRegistryStatusProvider.readExcludedPaths(WindowsDefenderRegistryStatusProvider.java:63)
        at com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.windows.WindowsDefenderRegistryStatusProvider.getExcludedPaths(WindowsDefenderRegistryStatusProvider.java:51)
        at com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker.getExcludedPatterns(WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker.java:243)
        at com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker.checkWindowsDefender(WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker.java:129)
        at com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker$1.lambda$projectOpened$0(WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker.java:92)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:295)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified.
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.registryGetValues(Advapi32Util.java:2268)
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.registryGetValues(Advapi32Util.java:2247)
        at com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.windows.WindowsDefenderRegistryStatusProvider.readExcludedPaths(WindowsDefenderRegistryStatusProvider.java:58)
        ... 14 more
2023-03-13 18:48:54,617 [  22792]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.gradle.variant.view.BuildVariantView)
2023-03-13 18:48:54,954 [  23129]   WARN - #c.i.BundleBase - ignore extra mnemonic in https://kotlinlang.org/lp/mobile/?utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_campaign=ASKMMW&utm_content={0}
2023-03-13 18:48:54,956 [  23131]   WARN - #c.i.BundleBase - ignore extra mnemonic in https://kotlinlang.org/lp/mobile/?utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_campaign=ASKMMW&utm_content={0}
2023-03-13 18:48:54,959 [  23134]   WARN - #c.i.BundleBase - ignore extra mnemonic in https://kotlinlang.org/lp/mobile/?utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_campaign=ASKMMW&utm_content={0}
2023-03-13 18:48:54,959 [  23134]   WARN - #c.i.BundleBase - ignore extra mnemonic in https://kotlinlang.org/lp/mobile/?utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_campaign=ASKMMW&utm_content={0}
2023-03-13 18:48:55,880 [  24055]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.w.WearPairingManager - Waited 1 seconds (plus 14346000 nanoseconds delay) for TrustedListenableFutureTask@64561ef3[status=PENDING, info=[task=[running=[NOT STARTED YET], com.android.tools.idea.adb.AdbService$$Lambda$1670/0x0000000101449840@69230add]]]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Waited 1 seconds (plus 14346000 nanoseconds delay) for TrustedListenableFutureTask@64561ef3[status=PENDING, info=[task=[running=[NOT STARTED YET], com.android.tools.idea.adb.AdbService$$Lambda$1670/0x0000000101449840@69230add]]]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:527)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:100)
        at com.android.tools.idea.wearpairing.WearPairingManager.findAdb(WearPairingManager.kt:434)
        at com.android.tools.idea.wearpairing.WearPairingManager.access$findAdb(WearPairingManager.kt:70)
        at com.android.tools.idea.wearpairing.WearPairingManager$connectedDevicesProvider$1.invoke(WearPairingManager.kt:92)
        at com.android.tools.idea.wearpairing.WearPairingManager$connectedDevicesProvider$1.invoke(WearPairingManager.kt:92)
        at com.android.tools.idea.wearpairing.WearPairingManager.getConnectedDevices(WearPairingManager.kt:440)
        at com.android.tools.idea.wearpairing.WearPairingManager.getAvailableDevices(WearPairingManager.kt:382)
        at com.android.tools.idea.wearpairing.WearPairingManager.updateListAndForwardState(WearPairingManager.kt:396)
        at com.android.tools.idea.wearpairing.WearPairingManager.access$updateListAndForwardState(WearPairingManager.kt:70)
        at com.android.tools.idea.wearpairing.WearPairingManager$setDeviceListListener$1.invokeSuspend(WearPairingManager.kt:207)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

Please help me understand what I am missing and how to resolve this issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it started working automatically after a few days. If anyone is facing the same error, you can raise an issue here, you will get help here:

```
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/273098792
```